# Moved sitemaps to a different subdomain and losing search referrals around the same time. Red herring or correlation?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

We started to lose search referral traffic around the same time that I moved some of our sitemaps to a subdomain. Could this have hurt us?

I followed [Google's steps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en&ref_topic=8476) to creating a sitemap under a different subdomain. The new sitemaps.foo.com subdomain is being crawled and indexed well.

Both www.foo.com and sitemaps.foo.com have been verified in Google Webmaster Tools. They appear as distinct sites. Is this correct? I can't find a way in Webmaster Tools to say "Hey, sitemaps.foo.com is really owned by www.foo.com, so show them together and make sure to attribute sitemaps.foo urls to www.foo"

Our www.foo.com/robots.txt

```
Sitemap: http://www.foo.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://sitemaps.foo.com/subdir/sitemap.xml.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

If you register `foo.com` in GWT, then it will report on everything on the entire domain including the subdomains `www.foo.com` and `sitemaps.foo.com`.

It is unlikely that moving your sitemaps had any effect on your rankings.  This is because sitemaps are not used for ranking purposes, only for URL discovery. (See: [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).)